# AngularJS filter by id returns multiple entrys

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

i had an array like this:

```
arr = [
    {ID: 502, Description: 'aaa', code: 1122},
    {ID: 2, Description: 'bbb', code: 2211},
    {ID: 700, Description: 'ccc', code: 2222}
];
```

when i try to filter the ID I get all occurences of the specific number:

```
$(filter)('filter')( arr, { ID: 2 } )[0]
```

returns entry one ID: 502 but it should return the entry with ID: 2

Where is my fault?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) it will returns a match containing that character, not an equal match. So therefore with your implementation thats how its designed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) when used with an object it will match the element if it contains the value.

> A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1".

There is a second option `comparator` passing `true` will cause it to perform a strict equality meaning it should only return exact matches.

```
$filter('filter')( arr, { ID: 2 }, true);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/enxbpjg0/

Comment: That's it! Sometimes i should read the docs more precisely. Thanks!

Comment: @Z3R0 Glad to help, Angulars docs are quite tricky to see all the different ways a method can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function instead of the object. So...

```
$filter('filter')(arr, function(value) {
  return value.ID === 2;
});
```